# Hbase mapreduce: Retrieve rows from hbase based on date

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

My row key format is ID|date.
Scenario: Whenever a request comes to add a row in hbase keep on adding it with ID and request date. There may not be rows for an ID everyday.

*** Ex: row1 - AB20160513
        row2 - XY20160514
        row3 - AB20160515***

Now I need row3 and row2 since it is the latest rows for an Id. How can I do this in java mapreduce? Just idea is sufficent if any code snippets it will be more grateful.